# Pass react inline style values as varaible in component load

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, inline-styles

I want to implement a 6x6 board using React. I decided to loop over m and n (here as 6 and 6) and make the cells with passing top and left css properties based in iterators. I've read many of the answers here about passing inline styles as variables, but maybe I fail in finding correct keywords.
This is what I did:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const Board = () => {
  const [boardPlate, setBoardPlate] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    boardPlateMaker(6, 6)
  }, []);

  const BoardCell = (offsetTop, offsetLeft, key) => {
    return (
      <div
        className="game-board__cell"
        style={{
          top: offsetTop,
          left: offsetLeft,
        }}
        key={key}
      ></div>
    );
  };

  const boardPlateMaker = (n, m) => {
    let cellHolder = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cellHolder.push(
          <BoardCell
            offsetTop={`${i * 10}%`}
            offsetLeft={`${j * 10}%`}
            key={`${i}${j}`}
          ></BoardCell>
        );
      }
    }
    setBoardPlate(cellHolder);
  };

  return <div>{boardPlate}</div>;
};
```

There is no error or warning, but for some reason the styles are not applied, although when I log the "BoardCell" react component array, each of them have this keys and values inside their props:

```
offsetLeft: "0%"
​​​
offsetTop: "30%"
​​​
```

All cells are rendered with top:0 and left:0 and have complete overlap.

I tried to make style objects inside each loop of boardPlateMaker and pass the whole object to each cell. Didn't work as well.

**UPDATE:**
I found it and it was noticing the props is an object in BoardCell:

```
const BoardCell = ({offsetTop, offsetLeft, key}) => {
    ...
  };
```

Instead of:

```
const BoardCell = (offsetTop, offsetLeft, key) => {
    ...
  };
```

But I still welcome any better suggestion :)

Comment: ```style={{top:`${i * 10}%`, left:`${j * 10}%`}}``` is correct, but note that `left` and `top` have no effect on statically positioned elements. Are you doing anything to make these [positioned elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, the position is absolute. But the styles are passed as string using template literals in boardPlateMaker.

Comment: Please show us the problem with that runnable Stack Snippet. (Side note: It's "Board" rather than "Borad".)